# Debugging a React app from console as if the console was the app itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, console

When I used to program with python I could run a python app and then execute methods and access variables of the app from within terminal. This was a great way to test things around.

Working on my JS app I often use console.log to try things out but I am looking for a way to try things without having to rerun the app each time. I want to be able to call any method / variable of my React app (including imported classes etc) from within console "at run-time".

Is this possible? If yes, how?

If not, what is the best alternative to switching between code and browser back-and-force to see the effect of certain changes console.log ?

Comment: you can use the debugger by only typing "debugger" in the code which will be like a breakpoint to start debugging

Comment: but this won't allow me to run any methods written in React. I want to be able to run methods of my app from the console.

Comment: yes, you can, but it depends on where did you put the debugger, you can put the debugger directly after the methods that you want, then you can call them